# Strange SharePoint mapping issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-server-2003

I have a SharePoint document library, mapped to a network drive, the path is

```
      Z:\[Document Library Name]\
```

If I browse the folder locally using windows explorer, I have no problems accessing the folder, and can create, edit and delete files and other folders.

But when I try copying using .net (standard stuff), I get an error saying the path could not be found.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Using 2003 Server

Comment: This is only happening from my 2003 Server installation, from 2008 server it works fine :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of you with the same problem, I found the solution....

It seems in Windows 2003 Server, even though you map a drive and assign it a connection profile, your .net code reads and writes to the mapped drive using the current context user profile.

This has changed in Windows 2008 Server, where .net respects the connection profile stored in the mapped drive settings.

Anyways - the solution is to impersonate and/or have correct permissions when you try to access that share from .net.